# Work with libsvm in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libsvm

I followed the steps in the readme of Libsvm to build on windows. I did the following successfully.

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat""
nmake -f Makefile.win clean all
```

But now how do I use libsvm now in Visual Studio. I need to integrate libsvm to a Visual Studio project and call svm-train and svm-predict from C++ code in Visual Studio. As the first step I would like to write a simple C++ program that can call svm-train and svm-predict. But I am lost after doing the above two steps as the documentation (readme and FAQ) are unclear afterwards. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm guessing the ninja make generated some dlls? you need to include those in your VS project.

Comment: @Aram no dlls were created, only some .obj files were created. What should I do with them?

Comment: Yes thank you I got it now. libsvm dll is create now. How do I use it in the c++ code?

Comment: Google on how to include a library in visual studio..

Comment: I included it already. I want to know how I create the model and use it using  svm-train and svm-predict.

Comment: I have no idea m8, I'm guessing the library came with an example or something.

Comment: The readme and the FAQ are not clear. No proper example is there.

Comment: If you read the readme carefully.. svm-toy is what you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Aram. I am going through it now. Thank you for your time. If you add all that as answer I can mark it correct. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reread your question, clean all just seems to clean your build files, effectively if you read the guide correctly it says that after cleaning you should run

```
"nmake -f Makefile.win lib"
```